# How to match 'K', 'M', 'G', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi' etc. but not solitary 'i' affix

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

What I am trying to do is match shorthand notation with ISO prefixes (`1k = 1000`, `-1ki = -1024`, etc.).  This regex is close:

```
^([+-]?)(\d+)((?i)[KMGTPEZY]?(?i)i?$)
```

But it matches `1i`, so I am trying to find a regex that will only match the `i` if it is preceded by one of the letters in the character class.  I tried using a lookbehind:

```
^([+-]?)(\d+)((?i)[KMGTPEZY]?(?<=(?i)[KMGTPEZY])(?i)i?$)
```

This won't match `1i`, but now it won't match a number with no prefix like `1`, and it seems... inelegant to have to repeat the `(?i)[KMGTPEZY]` so I was hoping there is a more graceful way of doing this... that also works in Python :-).

In case it affects the answer, the complete problem is I want to handle things like `1`,`2`,`3`,`[5-10)`,`20-25`,`1k-2k`,`2Mi-3Gi`,`10T`... substitute the appropriate number for the prefix shorthand (`1k=1000`, `10ki=10240`, etc) and then generate a list of the actual sequence (so expand `[5-10)` to `5,6,7,8,9`, `20-25` is equivalent to `[20-25]` or `20,21,22,23,24,25`), but right now, I am at the first step which is just matching the prefix shorthand notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite straightforward:

```
(?i)^([+-])?(\d+)([KMGTPEZY]i?)?$
```

Here we specify an optional group `([KMGTPEZY]i?)?` which itself contains the optional match `i?`.

Note that, as a global flag, `(?i)` need only be specified once (and is traditionally specified at the start of the regex where it's easily spotted). If you want to specify that the optional `i` part of the suffix **is** case sensitive, global flags won't help you, and you'll have to do something like this:

```
^([+-])?(\d+)([KkMmGgTtPpEeZzYy]i?)?$
```

Examples:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('(?i)^([+-])?(\d+)([KMGTPEZY]i?)?$')
```

```
>>> pattern.search('12').groups()
(None, '12', None)
```

```
>>> pattern.search('-34').groups()
('-', '34', None)
```

```
>>> pattern.search('+56m').groups()
('+', '56', 'm')
```

```
>>> pattern.search('-78ki').groups()
('-', '78', 'ki')
```

```
>>> pattern.search('90i').groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: Thanks much.  Not only did you answer my question, but I wasn't aware of the global nature of the case-insensitive flag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one could probably address this with fancy features.
But no, that's not necessary.

Simple alternation would suffice.

```
^([+-]?\d+)([KMGTPEZY]i|[KMGTPEZY]|)$
```

That is saying, e.g., that we'd like to match 'Ki', or match 'K', or match...